# Error 500. .htaccess for laravel routing (line RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]) with AMMPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

On AMMPS instalation of Apache 2.4.12 trought AMMPS, I get error 500 when try use .htaccess for routing pourposes (I use Illuminate\Routing & use Illuminate\Http, not full laravel)

When read apache log, only show

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Oct/2015:08:29:49 +0100] "GET /public HTTP/1.1" 500 528 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0"
```

Try put more level debug on Apache and see.

```
[Sat Oct 10 08:39:55.862342 2015] [core:error] [pid 41739] [client 127.0.0.1:65261] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

.htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine On

 # Redirect Trailing Slashes... 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

 # Handle Front Controller...
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] # If comment this line not error 500
```

If comment last line not error, but routing not work